# What queuing tools or algorithms support fair queuing of jobs

Tags: queue, priority-queue, task-queue

I am hitting a well known problem, but I can't find a simple answer that tells me how to solve it.

**I would appreciate you directing me by answering which feature I should look for in available queuing software or suitable algorithms if the solution requires programming in addition to the tools. and if you can direct me to Python supported tools, it would be helpful**

My problem is that I get over the span of the day jobs which deploy 10, 100 or 1000 tests (I exaggerate , but it helps make a point). Many jobs deploy 10 tests, some deploy 100 tests and one or two deploy 1000 tests.

I want to deploy the tests in such a manner that the delay in execution is spread in a fair manner between all jobs. Let me explain myself.

If the very large job takes 2 hours on a idle server, it would be acceptable if it completes after 4 hours.

If a small job takes 3 minutes on an idle server, it would be acceptable if it completes after 15 minutes.

I want the delay of running the jobs to be spread in a fair way, so jobs that started earlier  don't get too delayed. If it looks that the job is going to be delayed more than allowed it's priority will increase.

I think that prioritizing queues may be the solution, so dynamically changing the weights on a large queue will make it faster when needed.

Is there a queue software that knows how to do the above automatically. Lets say that I give  each job some time limit and the queue software knows how to prioritize the tests from each queue so that no job is delayed too much?

**Thanks.**

**Adding information following Jim's comments.**

> Not enough information to supply an answer. Is a job essentially just a list of tests? Can multiple tests for a single job be run concurrently? Do you always run all tests for a job? – Jim Mischel 14 hours ago

1. Each job deploys between 10 to 1000 tests.
2. The test can run concurrently to all other tests from the same or other users without conflicts.
3. All tests that were deploy by a job, are planned to run.

**Additional info:**

I've learned so far that Prioritized Queues are actually about applying weights to items in a single queue, where items with the hightest are pulled first. If two or more items have the same highest priority, the first item to arrive will be executed first.

When I pondered about Priority Queues it was more in the way of:

1. Multiple Queues, where each queue has a priority assigned to the entire queue.
2. The priority can be changed dynamically in runtime, based on some condition, e.g. setting a time limit on the execution of the entire queue.

Comment: Not enough information to supply an answer. Is a job essentially just a list of tests? Can multiple tests for a single job be run concurrently? Do you always run all tests for a job?

Comment: I am looking into MLFQ - Multilevel Feedback Queue Scheduling - to solve my problem. Hope to have something to answer here.